# App que a cada dia da semana mostra uma activity

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um app , que ao entrar nele , ele detecta a data e ja mostra a acitivity para aquela data , como eu faço isso? por exemplo hoje dia 07/08 , então ele irá mostrar a activity configurada para a data de 07/08

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso seja semanal, pode ser algo simples usando o `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`. Veja:

```
// resgata a data atual
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

Intent i = null;
switch (day) {
    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        i = new Intent(this, DomingoActivity.class);

    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        i = new Intent(this, SendaActivity.class);

    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        i = new Intent(this, TercaActivity.class);
    .
    .
    .
    //etc
}

startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de mudar a Activity a cada dia, tente criar um layout do qual você possa trocar seu conteúdo conforme a necessidade. Você poderia especificar mais que tipo de conteúdo pretendes colocar nesta Activity.

O ideal seria você ter de onde buscar o conteúdo do dia, como um Web service. Assim, você faria o download do material do dia e atualizaria os componentes desta Activity.

Caso você queira apenas realizar testes, experimente salvar algumas imagens na pasta `assets`e realize a atualização conforme o dia.